# Raising a float to the power of something creates a complex number - Python

Tags: python

When I try to raise a float number (PE: 0.1) to the power of anything, the script creates a complex number.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

precision = float(input('Introduce the precision that you want for the pi number: '))

i = precision
dif = precision
previous = 0

while dif >= precision:
    my_pi = ((-1)**i)/(2*i+1)
    res = previous + my_pi
    dif = abs(res) - anterior
    anterior = res
    i+= precision

print('The final approximation of pi is {0:.6f}'.format(resultado*4))
```

But after the 'first round' it crashes giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/al343729/VJ1203/Prácticas/Práctica 2/Ejer07.py", line 14, in <module>
    while dif >= precision:
TypeError: unorderable types: complex() >= float()
```

This doesn't happens with a FOR loop

Comment: Whats this for? `(-1)**i`

Comment: What do you expect raising -1 to a fractional power to do?

Comment: @user2357112 so why that happens to me but not a friend with the EXACTLY SAME operation?

Comment: If you want `(-1)**i` to effectively flip the sign of each term, you need to ask yourself why you're setting `i = precision` and `i += precision"..

Comment: You also appear to be using the variable `anterior` before you assign it a value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import math at the beginning of the program and then use `math.pow()` instead of `()**()`. I had the same problem before, but now it works. You also used `anterior` and `resultado` before assigning them.